# Can the same SQLite table be reached by different Android devices?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am using a SQLite database for same application on two different devices. The problem is, they both seem to have different tables (first one has some entries, the second one is empty). I wonder if the SQLite tables are just saved locally and can't be reached by other devices, or can they be reached from any Android device?

Comment: They are stored locally only

Answer (score 0):

SQLite databases are indeed stored locally on the device.

If you want to share data between different devices, you either need the devices to connect to each other, or you need to set up a web server to handle storing shared data.

Comment: There are hacks to get around it, like the one in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the database on a network file system/dropbox/etc. and access them that way, but sqlite3 is not meant to be a client-server database.